# libsodium.dll wont load

Tags: encryption

I have windows 11.
vim 9.0
When I write a blowfish encrypted file it gives me this error. It still writes the file and encrypts it even with the error

E370: Could not load library libsodium.dll: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: So have you libsodium available? Most likely Vim writes with an old encryption method instead

Comment: Is libsodium.dll available next to the vim.exe or gVim.exe? How do you have installed Vim (using the archive from vim.org vim90rt.zip, using the installer from vim.org gvim90.exe, from [tuxproject](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/), ...)

Comment: I installed with: -rwxrwxrwx 1 bob bob  9828024 Oct  5 11:50 gvim_9.0.0000_x86_signed.exe

Comment: I have the files in the same dir: bob@bobr5:/mnt/c/vim/vim90$ ls -l gvim.exe libsodium.dll
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bob bob 3443712 Jun 28 09:10 gvim.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bob bob  300544 May 30  2019 libsodium.dll

Comment: I also observed gvim process with procexp and it never loads libsodium.dll.

Comment: IF you want to make use of *libsodium*, you need to `:set cryptmethod=xchacha20` Then when writing the file, vim should output `[xchacha20]` in the command line and this shows, that is writing using libsodium

Comment: Tried above didn't work.  
opened file.  
set cryptmethod
cryptmethod=blowfish2
set cryptmethod=xchacha20
:w
E370: could not load libsodium.dll (7 times)